# How CMake distrubute third party lib with executable bin script

Tags: c, cmake

I want to distribute a standalone binary script with cmake.

basiclly, it looks like:

```
Folder
  |- bin-script
  |- 3rd
      |- liblib1.so
      |- liblib2.so
```

I hope after user get this folder, copy it to anywhere, then he can use the bin-script directly without install any 3rd libs but directly link to the libs provided in 3rd folder.

I try to add link directory with

```
set_target_properties(${LIB_NAME}-bin PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-L./3rd")
```

but it seems not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RPATH` contains a list of search paths for the linker.
You can add to it as you would to any other CMake list:

```
if(APPLE)
    list(APPEND CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "@executable_path/3rd")
    list(APPEND CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "@executable_path/")
elseif(UNIX)
    list(APPEND CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "\$ORIGIN/3rd")
endif()
```

Comment: I try -Wl,-rpath,./3rd -lcurl, it works, but if i move target folder to another location, it still could not find the lib. Event i use a relative path, but indeed it still convert to absolute path finally i think.

Comment: Depending on the ldlib you need a placeholder for the executable folder, `$ORIGIN` (don't forget to escape it!) on Linux and `@executable_path` on macOS